# Serve content from a different server in a ASP.NET MVC 3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Currently `Url.Content("a.jpg")` would return something like "/a.jpg"

Is there a way to force all content to be served from another server?

I want `Url.Content("a.jpg")` to return something like: "http://**somehost**/a.jpg"

Answer (score 3):

The `Url.Content` helper works only with internal to the current application urls. If you want to work with external urls you could write a custom url helper for that purpose:

```
public static class UrlExtensions
{
    public static string ContentExternal(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string contentPath)
    {
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://somehost");
        uriBuilder.Path = contentPath;
        return uriBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@Url.ContentExternal("/Content/images/a.jpg")
```